# keeping the order of invoices after deletion in mysql - laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Whenever a user is inserting an invoice on our laravel app, it numbers the respective invoice. so if they enter the first invoice ever, then it will be invoice 1, second invoice will be invoice 2 and so on

The number (1, 2, 3, ..., x) is basically the id (which is the primary key of the invoices table). But now let's say that there are 30 invoices and he wants to delete the 25th one, the next one that will be inserted won't be number 25, it will be 31, because it creates a new record in the table, and it should be 25 because that's the one that's missing

My question is, how can I automatically set the next number of the invoice to be the first one that's missing? I have a feeling that I should create a new column which indicates the number of the invoice. This is the code that's creating the invoice:

```
        $invoice = new \App\Models\Invoice();
        $invoice->provider_id = $request->input('provider-select');
        $invoice->number = $request->input('document-number');
        $invoice->document_date = $request->input('document-date');
        $invoice->due_date = $request->input('due-date');
        $invoice->discount_procent = $request->input('discount-procent');
        $invoice->discount_value = $request->input('discount-value');
        $invoice->total = $request->input('total-value');
        $invoice->insertion_date = $request->input('insertion-date');
        $invoice->save();
```

Should I create a new column called `numbering` and assign each invoice a number in ascending order, and when one invoices gets delete, to detected the one that's missing and then assign the next invoice with the number and filter them by `numerotate` and not by `id`?

Comment: If that is the logic you are going for then, yes adding a new field is best you will not be able to alter a pk auto increment field (like ID) without potentially breaking any table that references that PK as a FK.   even if you don't have a table now that references it, in the future you could. (pk - primary key)  (fk - foreign key)

Comment: If you wanted to keep the order it might be better/easier to put a delete flag field (could be a 0 default and 1 if deleted) on the table, for your display query just don't display the row with the delete flag set.  Then when you want to insert a new row, do a quick query of deleteflag = 1 order by id asc limit 1  and if you have a row, just update all the fields and if you do not insert a new row.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will 100% consider it! the thing is, on that invoice there are products, so this might mean to update them as well. I will see if this will be the best solution

Answer (score -1):

Yes,rather you should make a new field. You should not touch the primary key handling.

You can make a new field,let's say `sequence`.
Before inserting the new data check the missing sequence in `invoice` table and assign it to that sequence.

**EDIT** -
If you want to generate year wise sequence, you need to maintain a `year` column and for retrieve records use both `sequence` and `year` column.

Comment: Nice, so my idea was good! I should do the same with all documents, not only with the invoices. But another question would be, the sequence would have to reset each year, so if the last invoice of 2022 will have the sequence 167, then the first one of 2023 should be again 1, and so on. How can I achieve this as well?

Comment: @Cristian25 you may have to create an additional lookup table instead, this would be something like ID(auto inc for indexing) , InvoiceID (fk from invoice table) , year,  invoiceNumber

Comment: should the year be inserted automatically? also, invoiceNumber is the sequence, right? how can I apply the same concept for another type of documents, let's say transfers? should I create another lookup table for transfers?

Comment: There are actually many approaches to store the year and  sequence.You can either store them as json data, or you can make 2 columns(1 for year and 1 for sequence).You need to think as per your structure and number of documents and size of your tables

Comment: @Cristian25 yes invoicenumber is the sequence, and yes you could add another column to the same table something like formType and indicate if it is an invoice or a transfer, or create a separate table all together.   At this point you are talking design,  I would suggest that you read some books on database architecture and determine what is best for your situation.